# Find all matches in column and add them from a different column?

Tags: excel

First off, I am not sure if this is even possible. I have have researched google and have come up with no solution. Your my last hope.

Basically I am trying to build an excel sheet to measure progress in workouts.

I have a tab called 'Week 1' which is where you enter in all the data. Looks like this...

[image]

What I basically need to do is select each row in column D that has Military Push-up in column B. So I would have D7 & D20. After that I need to add it up and put it in the following location. That location is E3 in the picture below.

[image]

So in this picture E3 should say 40, but it says 20. That is because it does not add up.

My current formula is

```
=IF(ISNA(INDEX('Week 1'!D:D, MATCH(SelectedExercise, 'Week 1'!$B:$B, 0))), 0, INDEX('Week 1'!D:D, MATCH(SelectedExercise, 'Week 1'!$B:$B, 0)))
```

I need it to select all of the cells and add them up... not just the first one. I have tried many things, but have not even gotten close to what I need. Not sure what to do next. What should I do?

Please note, if you do not understand something... just ask.

Thank you for your time, I truly appreciate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMIF.

`=SUMIF(Week1!D:D, $B3, Week1!$B:$B)`

Also, if you want to do it for multiple weeks, then I suggest the following which also works for multiple exercices.

`=SUMIF(INDIRECT($D3) & "!D:D", $B3, INDIRECT($D3) & "!B:B")`

Comment: I am so mad that you answered this with such speed and I spent hours trying to figure it out... and what I hate even more is the solution was so simple. However, thank you so much. I couldn't have done this without you. Also, thanks for the update to your answer... I just need the first part, but the second part is nice to know.